# How to have datepicker in PhoneGap application for all android devices

Tags: android, cordova, datepicker, phonegap-plugins

I have built a PhoneGap application using the PhoneGap build engine (http://build.phonegap.com).

My problem is, on some devices, the date-picker is automatically available. But on some devices, it doesn't work. I read that every android using device may use a different javascript engine and PhoneGap is using on Android an engine which doesn't support the date-picker.

My questions are

1. Can I force my application on PhoneGap to use Chrome engine?
2. if not, which plugin would you recommend and how I can implement a plugin on PhoneGap build
3. Any other suggestion

thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have tried using the native widget DatePicker in my PhoneGap application and I gave up, different versions of Android behaves differently. Late versions of Android running the Chrome engine works OK (as you say), but older does not.

If you want true cross-platform across all versions you should probably take a look at the 3rd party PhoneGap plugins:

https://build.phonegap.com/plugins